# Getting the error:- org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-annotations

I am new to Spring and we are using a Spring Batch to process jobs
I am posting my whole code below,Please share you knowledge:-

This is the Main class file Name with SpringBatchAdmin:-

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { BatchAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
        WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class })
//@Import(MainV1Configuration.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { BatchConfiguration.class })
@Import(value={MainV2Configuration.class, FTPConfiguration.class})
public class SpringBatchAdmin extends SpringBootServletInitializer     

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBatchAdmin.class, args);
    }    
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SpringBatchAdmin.class);
    }
}
```

The MainV2Configuration file

```
import java.io.File;import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpSessionFactory;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

@Configuration
@ImportResource(
        value = {
                "classpath:org/springframework/batch/admin/web/resources/servlet-config.xml",
                "classpath:org/springframework/batch/admin/web/resources/webapp-config.xml"
         }
    )
public class MainV2Configuration {  
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() { 
        Resource[] resources = {
            new ClassPathResource("batch-hsql.properties"),
            new ClassPathResource("customercare-job.properties")
        };
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer bean = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        bean.setLocations(resources);
        return bean; 
    } 
  }
```

The BatchConfiguration file:-

```
package ccp.batch.config;
import java.io.File;import java.util.Arrays;import java.util.List;
import javax.sql.DataSource;  
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.JobRegistry;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.explore.JobExplorer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobOperator;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobOperator;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.ListItemReader;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpSessionFactory;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

import com.batch.tasklet.FtpGetRemoteFilesTasklet;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing(modular = true)
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Value("${batch.jdbc.driver}")
    private String driverClassName;

    @Value("${batch.jdbc.url}")
    private String driverUrl;

    @Value("${batch.jdbc.user}")
    private String driverUsername;

    @Value("${batch.jdbc.password}")
    private String driverPassword;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("jobRepository")
    private JobRepository jobRepository;

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    private Job job;

    @Autowired
    JobExplorer jobExplorer;

    @Autowired
    JobRegistry jobRegistry;

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job").start(step()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step").chunk(1).reader(reader()).writer(writer()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemReader<String> reader() {
        return new ListItemReader<String>(Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3"));
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<? super Object> writer() {
        return new ItemWriter<Object>() {
            @Override
            public void write(List<? extends Object> items) throws Exception {
                System.out.println(items);
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public JobOperator jobOperator() {
        SimpleJobOperator jobOperator = new SimpleJobOperator();
        jobOperator.setJobExplorer(jobExplorer);
        jobOperator.setJobLauncher(jobLauncher);
        jobOperator.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry);
        jobOperator.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        return jobOperator;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        dataSource.setUrl(driverUrl);
        dataSource.setUsername(driverUsername);
        dataSource.setPassword(driverPassword);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher() {
        SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        return jobLauncher;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
    }

}
```

The  FTPConfiguration file

```
package ccp.batch.config;

import java.io.File;import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpSessionFactory;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import ccp.batch.tasklet.FtpGetRemoteFilesTasklet;

@Configuration
public class FTPConfiguration {

    @Value("${batch.jdbc.driver}")
    private String driverClassName;

    @Value("${batch.jdbc.url}")
    private String driverUrl;

    @Value("${batch.jdbc.user}")
    private String driverUsername;

    @Value("${batch.jdbc.password}")
    private String driverPassword;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("jobRepository")
    private JobRepository jobRepository;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myFtpSessionFactory")
    private SessionFactory myFtpSessionFactory;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        dataSource.setUrl(driverUrl);
        dataSource.setUsername(driverUsername);
        dataSource.setPassword(driverPassword);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value="step")
    public FtpGetRemoteFilesTasklet myFtpGetRemoteFilesTasklet()
    {
        FtpGetRemoteFilesTasklet  ftpTasklet = new FtpGetRemoteFilesTasklet();
        ftpTasklet.setRetryIfNotFound(true);
        ftpTasklet.setDownloadFileAttempts(3);
        ftpTasklet.setRetryIntervalMilliseconds(10000);
        ftpTasklet.setFileNamePattern("README");
        //ftpTasklet.setFileNamePattern("TestFile");
        ftpTasklet.setRemoteDirectory("/");
        ftpTasklet.setLocalDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")));
        ftpTasklet.setSessionFactory(myFtpSessionFactory);

        return ftpTasklet;
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory myFtpSessionFactory()
    {
        DefaultFtpSessionFactory ftpSessionFactory = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();

        ftpSessionFactory.setHost("ftp.gnu.org");
        ftpSessionFactory.setClientMode(0);
        ftpSessionFactory.setFileType(0);
        ftpSessionFactory.setPort(21);
        ftpSessionFactory.setUsername("anonymous");
        ftpSessionFactory.setPassword("anonymous");
        return ftpSessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher() {
        SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        return jobLauncher;
    }
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
    }
    }
```

The FtpGetRemoteFilesTasklet  file

```
package ccp.batch.tasklet;

import java.io.File;import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.List;   
import org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepContribution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.ChunkContext;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.Tasklet;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.integration.file.filters.SimplePatternFileListFilter;
import org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer;
import org.springframework.integration.ftp.filters.FtpSimplePatternFileListFilter;
import org.springframework.integration.ftp.inbound.FtpInboundFileSynchronizer;
import org.springframework.integration.sftp.filters.SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter;
import org.springframework.integration.sftp.inbound.SftpInboundFileSynchronizer;
import org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;

public class FtpGetRemoteFilesTasklet implements Tasklet, InitializingBean
{
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FtpGetRemoteFilesTasklet.class);

    private File localDirectory;
    private AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer<?> ftpInboundFileSynchronizer;
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private boolean autoCreateLocalDirectory = true;
    private boolean deleteLocalFiles = true;
    private String fileNamePattern;
    private String remoteDirectory;
    private int downloadFileAttempts = 12;
    private long retryIntervalMilliseconds = 300000;
    private boolean retryIfNotFound = false;


       public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception 
    {
        Assert.notNull(sessionFactory, "sessionFactory attribute cannot be null");
        Assert.notNull(localDirectory, "localDirectory attribute cannot be null");
        Assert.notNull(remoteDirectory, "remoteDirectory attribute cannot be null");
        Assert.notNull(fileNamePattern, "fileNamePattern attribute cannot be null");

        setupFileSynchronizer();
            if (!this.localDirectory.exists())  {
            if (this.autoCreateLocalDirectory)  {
                if (logger.isDebugEnabled())   {
                    logger.debug("The '" + this.localDirectory + "' directory doesn't exist; Will create.");
                }
                this.localDirectory.mkdirs();
            }
            else {
                throw new FileNotFoundException(this.localDirectory.getName());
            }
        }
    }

    private void setupFileSynchronizer()
    {
        if (isSftp()) {
            ftpInboundFileSynchronizer = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizer(sessionFactory);
            ((SftpInboundFileSynchronizer) ftpInboundFileSynchronizer).setFilter(new SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter(fileNamePattern));
        }
        else  {
            ftpInboundFileSynchronizer = new FtpInboundFileSynchronizer(sessionFactory);
            ((FtpInboundFileSynchronizer) ftpInboundFileSynchronizer).setFilter(new FtpSimplePatternFileListFilter(fileNamePattern));
        }
        ftpInboundFileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory(remoteDirectory);
    }

    private void deleteLocalFiles()
    {
        if (deleteLocalFiles) {
            SimplePatternFileListFilter filter = new SimplePatternFileListFilter(fileNamePattern);
            List<File> matchingFiles = filter.filterFiles(localDirectory.listFiles());
            if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(matchingFiles)) {
                for (File file : matchingFiles)  {
                    FileUtils.deleteQuietly(file);
                }
            }
        }
    }

        public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception
    {
        deleteLocalFiles();

        ftpInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(localDirectory);

        if (retryIfNotFound) {
            SimplePatternFileListFilter filter = new SimplePatternFileListFilter(fileNamePattern);
            int attemptCount = 1;
            while (filter.filterFiles(localDirectory.listFiles()).size() == 0 && attemptCount <= downloadFileAttempts)  {
                logger.info("File(s) matching " + fileNamePattern + " not found on remote site.  Attempt " + attemptCount + " out of " + downloadFileAttempts);
                Thread.sleep(retryIntervalMilliseconds);
                ftpInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(localDirectory);
                attemptCount++;
            }

            if (attemptCount >= downloadFileAttempts && filter.filterFiles(localDirectory.listFiles()).size() == 0) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("Could not find remote file(s) matching " + fileNamePattern + " after " + downloadFileAttempts + " attempts.");
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
Some getters and setters methods *.*
```

The FirstTasklet file

```
package ccp.batch.tasklet;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepContribution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.ChunkContext;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.Tasklet;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;

public class FirstTasklet implements Tasklet {

    private String property; 
    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution arg0, ChunkContext arg1) throws Exception {
       System.out.println(property);
       return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }
public void setProperty(String property) {
        this.property = property;
    }
}
```

Two properties file in the src/main/resource directory

batch-hsql.properties
customer-job.properties

Other things i don't Know:-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcwuc.png)

This are in the xml files:-
First-job.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="">// Deleted here because there is limit of characters when posting a question on stackocerflow

    <batch:job id="FirstJob" restartable="true">
        <batch:step id="firstStep">
            <batch:tasklet ref="firstTasklet" start-limit="1" />
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>
    <bean id="firstTasklet" class="ccp.batch.tasklet.FirstTasklet">
        <property name="property" value="${custom-property}" />
    </bean>
    <batch:job id="FtpJob">
        <batch:step id="step1"  >           
            <batch:tasklet ref="myFtpGetRemoteFilesTasklet" />
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>
</beans>
```

Launch-contect.xml file:-

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <beans xmlns="">// Deleted here because there is limit of characters when posting a question on stackocerflow
                <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:batch.properties" />
            <context:component-scan base-package="ccp.batch" />
            <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
            <jdbc:script location="${batch.schema.script}" />
    </jdbc:initialize-database>
            <batch:job-repository id="jobRepository" />
                <import resource="classpath:/META-INF/spring/module-context.xml" />
      </beans>
```

The below is the error i am getting:-

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.batch.admin.web.JobController#0' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/sandy/.m2/repository/org/springframework/batch/spring-batch-admin-manager/1.3.0.RELEASE/spring-batch-admin-manager-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/META-INF/spring/batch/servlet/manager/controller-context.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.batch.admin.service.JobService]: : Error creating bean with name 'jobService' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/sandy/.m2/repository/org/springframework/batch/spring-batch-admin-manager/1.3.0.RELEASE/spring-batch-admin-manager-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/META-INF/spring/batch/bootstrap/manager/execution-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jobRepository' while setting bean property 'jobRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/sandy/.m2/repository/org/springframework/batch/spring-batch-admin-manager/1.3.0.RELEASE/spring-batch-admin-manager-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/META-INF/spring/batch/bootstrap/manager/execution-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobService' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/sandy/.m2/repository/org/springframework/batch/spring-batch-admin-manager/1.3.0.RELEASE/spring-batch-admin-manager-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/META-INF/spring/batch/bootstrap/manager/execution-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jobRepository' while setting bean property 'jobRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/sandy/.m2/repository/org/springframework/batch/spring-batch-admin-manager/1.3.0.RELEASE/spring-batch-admin-manager-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/META-INF/spring/batch/bootstrap/manager/execution-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:747)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1114)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1017)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
    at ccp.batch.SpringBatchAdmin.main(SpringBatchAdmin.java:41)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobService' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/sandy/.m2/repository/org/springframework/batch/spring-batch-admin-manager/1.3.0.RELEASE/spring-batch-admin-manager-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/META-INF/spring/batch/bootstrap/manager/execution-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jobRepository' while setting bean property 'jobRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/sandy/.m2/repository/org/springframework/batch/spring-batch-admin-manager/1.3.0.RELEASE/spring-batch-admin-manager-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/META-INF/spring/batch/bootstrap/manager/execution-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1017)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:811)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:739)
    ... 18 more
```

Comment: You are trying very hard not to use Spring Boot and Spring Integration. You are using frameworks and the first thing you do is work around those frameworks. I strongly suggest a read on the frameworks you are using and how to use them properly instead of hacking around them. Also you have Spring Batch Admin but do you really need it?

Comment: @M.Deinum I am new to this and i am reading but this will give me some confidence if this thing run...

Comment: Have you actually read the stack trace? The root cause is that your db connection isn't working.